# Problems with creating new user in firebase

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

There's something wrong with this function here, that I'cant find the reason for, I'm trying to add new users to my firebase database, and it doesn't work

```
exports.createUserWithEmailAndPassword = functions.https.onCall(
    async(data, context) => {
        const { adminEmail, adminPassword, adminNome, role, isActive } = data;

        if (context.auth.token.roles.includes("admin")) {
            const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
                email: adminEmail,
                password: adminPassword,
                displayName: adminNome
            });
            const customClaims = {
                roles: [role],
            };
            await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
            await db.collection("admin-roles").doc(user.uid).set({
                    uid: user.uid,
                    adminEmail,
                    adminPassword,
                    adminNome,
                    role,
                    isActive: true,
                    registeredAt: Date.now()
                }, { merge: true })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(
                        `User "${adminNome}" created. Custom claim added: "${customClaims.roles}"`
                    );
                    return {
                        uid,
                        adminEmail,
                        adminPassword,
                        adminNome,
                        role,
                        isActive,
                        registeredAt
                    };
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                        "Erro interno",
                        "Erro ao criar usuário",
                        error
                    );
                });
        } else {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "unauthenticated",
                "Only admins can create users."
            );
        }
    }
);
```

it should work with these functions

```
async signUp({ adminEmail, adminPassword, adminNome, role, isActive}: any): Promise<void> {
this.fns
  .httpsCallable('createUserWithEmailAndPassword')({ adminEmail, adminPassword, adminNome, role, isActive }).subscribe({
    next: response => {
      console.log('Usuário criado com sucesso!');
    },
    error: (err: FirebaseError) => {
      console.log(
        `${err.message}: Erro ao cadastrar usuário. Tente novamente.`
      );
    }
  });
```

}

```
signUp() {
    this.adminNovo.adminPassword = ''

    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      this.adminNovo.adminPassword += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }
    console.log(this.adminNovo)
    this.adminService.signUp(this.adminNovo).then(
      (res: any) => console.log(res)
    )

  }
```

But there's something wrong with my firebase function that is stopping the creation, in the console it calls exactly the first function

error in console

[image]

So I've looked in the logs in firebase

```
error code: Erro interno.
    at new HttpsError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:69:19)
    at /workspace/index.js:89:19
    at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:66:41)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:385:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)


{
insertId: "6329b7680004d257cbcc04fa"
labels: {
execution_id: "xss82uddvcsm"
instance_id: "00c61b117c54f94608670deae52421503ae18f031859611f1e55f4b3ec13c0990192a31900a81fb99db4d03e7cf36203f4726c29cb6acb0f1545"
}
logName: "projects/dev-processo-seletivo/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-09-20T12:51:52.643048282Z"
resource: {
labels: {3}
type: "cloud_function"
}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Invalid request, unable to process."
timestamp: "2022-09-20T12:51:52.315991Z"
trace: "projects/dev-processo-seletivo/traces/f3e3336110816f1a5e7dfc609827f649"
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: yes, i will update my post to share the error that i get

Comment: What is the exact code at line 7476?

Comment: it is in the function signUp, it is the console.log(res).
But i've found the error, don't know how to fix it yet, the data comes to firebase but it stops at the first If. I can log the context, auth and the toke... So the problem starts there, in this if right in the begning because the data is returned in a function.logger

Answer (score 0):

You don't share any error but there are two thing you should adapt:

1. Avoid mixing `then()` with `async`/`await`.
2. Declare `registeredAt` and `user.uid` as variables.

Also note that you don't pass any value for `isActive` when you call the CF from your front-end.

---

```
exports.createUserWithEmailAndPassword = functions.https.onCall(
    async (data, context) => {
        try {
            const { adminEmail, adminPassword, adminNome, role, isActive } = data;

            if (context.auth.token.roles.includes("admin")) {
                const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
                    email: adminEmail,
                    password: adminPassword,
                    displayName: adminNome
                });
                const customClaims = {
                    roles: [role],
                };

                const userId = user.uid;

                await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, customClaims);

                const registeredAt = Date.now();  // You could use FieldValue.serverTimestamp()  // Add const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue; at the top of the index.js file

                await db.collection("admin-roles").doc(user.uid).set({
                    uid: userId,
                    adminEmail,
                    adminPassword,
                    adminNome,
                    role,
                    isActive: true,
                    registeredAt
                }, { merge: true });

                console.log(`User "${adminNome}" created. Custom claim added: "${customClaims.roles}"`);

                return {
                    uid: userId,
                    adminEmail,
                    adminPassword,
                    adminNome,
                    role,
                    isActive: true,
                    registeredAt
                };

            } else {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                    "unauthenticated",
                    "Only admins can create users."
                );
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "Erro interno",
                "Erro ao criar usuário",
                error
            );
        }

    });
```

Comment: I wasn't the one that made this function, this is a project at the end of a course, and we are working on a already made product. But could you explain, or share something where explains why i shouldn't mix then() async/await?

Comment: Updated with the log errors found on firebase, i've changed the function but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Well we've managed to find the solution, and I think Renaud kind of pointed in that direction and I've must have missed.

Since the data was coming but wasn't passing through the try we made a verification first.

```
async function verifyUserAdmin(uid) {
    const result = await db.collection('admin-roles').doc(uid).get();
    const user = result.data();
    return user.role.includes("admin");
}
```

then we inserted into the the try so it would pass the verification

```
exports.createUserWithEmailAndPassword = functions.https.onCall(
    async (data, context) => {
        try {
            const { adminEmail, adminPassword, adminNome, role, isActive } = data;
            const idUsuario = context.auth.token.uid;
            if (verifyUserAdmin(idUsuario)) {
                const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
                    email: adminEmail,
                    password: adminPassword,
                    displayName: adminNome
                });
                const customClaims = {
                    admin: true
                };
                const userId = user.uid;
                await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, customClaims);
                const registeredAt = Date.now();
                await db.collection("admin-roles").doc(user.uid).set({
                    uid: userId,
                    adminEmail,
                    adminPassword,
                    adminNome,
                    role,
                    isActive: true,
                    registeredAt
                }, { merge: true });
                console.log(`User "${adminNome}" created. Custom claim added: "${customClaims.roles}"`);
                return {
                    uid: userId,
                    adminEmail,
                    adminPassword,
                    adminNome,
                    role,
                    isActive: true,
                    registeredAt
                };
            } else {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                    "unauthenticated",
                    "Only admins can create users."
                );
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "Erro interno",
                "Erro ao criar usuário",
                error
            );
        }
    });
```

And now we can finally add users in our database through the app